# Show that if $f(0)=0$, $f'>0$, $f''<0$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f(x)\over{x}}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

For a larger lemma I made in my paper, I'm trying to prove a small statement which claims that:

If $f$ is continues and derivable twice and, $f(0)=0; f'>0; f''<0$.
Then:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f(x)\over{x}}=0$

I could not find a reasoning why this is true.

I came up with this because of my intuition that $f$ is concave and thus after 1 it should converge to infinity but slower then x. And saw that functions like $\sqrt{x}$ are confirming this statement true.

I'm looking for an hint in the right direction how to prove/disprove it? Is this statement even true?

Comment: If $f =0$ you have nothing to prove

Comment: you are right, I corrected my question to f(0)=0. Thanks @JoeShmo

Comment: $f(x) = x + \arctan(x)$ would seem to be a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks! So I need to adjust my assumptions :) @DanielSchepler

Comment: Note that under your hypotheses the derivative $f'$ tends to a non-negative limit $L$ and the ratio $f(x) /x$ also tends to $L$ via L'Hospital's Rule. There is no guarantee that $L=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't true, as shown by @DanielSchepler, but if you add the assumption that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}{f'(x)} = 0$ then the theorem is true, this is the proof.

> Let $f : [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable at any point and such that
> $$f(0) = 0$$
> $$f'(x) \geq 0 \;\;\forall x \in [0,+\infty)$$
> $$f''(x) \leq 0 \;\; \forall x \in [0,+\infty)$$
> $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}{ f'(x) } = 0$$
>
> Then
> $\lim_{x \to +\infty}{\frac{f(x) }{x}} = 0$

Proof :

Using the fact that $f' \geq 0$ I know that $f$ is an increasing function, from which I get

$\frac{f(x)}{x} \geq 0$.

Now let $0 < y < x$, one has

$$\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{f(y) - f(0)}{x} + \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x} \leq \frac{f(y) - f(0)}{x} + \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}$$

Using [MVT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) and the fact that $f'$ is decreasing one gets

$$\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \leq f'(y)$$

So you have that for any $0 < y < x$ the following holds

$$0 \leq \frac{f(x)}{x} \leq \frac{f(y)}{x} + f'(y)$$

And now the theorem is trivial.

Comment: If we assume that $f'$ tends to $0$ then via L'Hospital's Rule $f(x) /x\to 0$. Further note that according to hypotheses of the question $f'$ tends to a non negative limit $L$ and by L'Hospital's Rule the ratio $f(x) /x$ also tends to $L$.

Comment: @Paul, thanks. I'll see if I can use these assumptions. 
Just to make the triviality clear, is it becasue you use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: Actually the proof is easier then the one I wrote, as shown by @ParamanandSingh. Anyway once you proved the final inequality to complete the proof you take any $\epsilon > 0$ and then you pick an $y > 0$ such that $f'(y) < \epsilon / 2$, then let $x > \max\{y, 2f(y)/\epsilon\}$ and see what happens.

Comment: @Paul this actually relaxes the extra assumptions of $f' \geq 0$ instead of just $f>0$ that I needed.